# how can select all element except of a div and child of divs in jquery

Tags: jquery, select, tags, element

I want select all HTML elements except of a div and child of div for assign an event

the elements is like this:

```
<span 1 id="select1"></span>
<span 2 id="select2"></span>
<span 3 id="select3"></span>
<span 4 id="select4"></span>
<span 5 id="select5"></span>
<span 6 id="select6"></span>

<!-- here is elements that i don't want select that -->
<div id="dontSelect">
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        don't select my element
      </td>
     </tr>
</table>
</div>
<!-- here is elements that i don't want select that -->
```

how can select like this?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an easier solution could be is to attach the handler to the document element, then check whether the event's target is inside the `dontSelect` element if so don't do anything

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('#dontSelect')) {
        //do your stuff
    }
})
```

But if you want to target only `span` elements then

```
$('span:not(#dontSelect span)').click(function(){
    //your stuff
})
```

or

```
$(':not(#dontSelect, #dontSelect *)').click(function(){
    //your stuff
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For all span element, You can try,

```
$('span');
```

For all spans having id started from `select` You can try

```
$("span[id^='select']");
```

For any element, You can try

```
$('*').not('#dontSelect, #dontSelect *')
```